# Start Datamenu only one time

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, startup

I have to make a Pedometer app for school.
The first time that someone opens my app, i want to open a screen, where the user can fill in about her/his length, gender...
Allthough I am quit new to android programming, and I really have no clue how I can open datascreen for only one time.
Can someone please help me out? Thanks!
Kind regards

Comment: Use shared pefrence for that

Comment: yes, that's what i thought, only i have no idea how i can use it like that?

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use sharedpreference:
when the user fills data that time you can save the data in sharedpreference .
here is the code you can use for storing data in sharedpreferance

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences =    getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();`
```

by this way you can save data;
when you load screen for first time check wheather data is there or not .
if data is present just switch the screen 
if not take data of user. 
for more reference 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

hope this will  help you. good luck